# Pattern for Regexp-replace string with different formatting

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, regexp-replace

I need to replace parts of queries similar to

```
    (ls.map_x BETWEEN
    '016'
    AND '018')
```

I have a problem with different formatting of newlines. So I'd like to create a universal pattern that would not be affected by different formating/

Comment: Is there always a ls.map_x? Is there always a BETWEEN? How similar is similar? Too many questions left open before anyone can give a meaningfull answer.

Comment: Changes only numbers which I can replace  with '\d+' and newline characters and spaces format

Comment: Is the text you want to manipulate stored in the database or are you editing a text file?  Show a few before and after examples that use all of the scenario's you need to allow for.  More info needed!